# Mono/Xamarin WebApi2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, mono

Does Mono/Xamarin Studio support Asp.Net WebApi2?

I can get MVC running, and I can get the demo from [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) working.... but I get the following at runtime

`System.TypeLoadException
Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HttpRouteExceptionHandler' from assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.`

`Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Web.
Exception stack trace:
  at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache (System.Web.HttpContextBase context) [0x00054] in /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-3.8.0/mcs/class/System.Web.Routing/System.Web.Routing/UrlRoutingModule.cs:128 
  at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache (System.Object o, System.EventArgs e) [0x00007] in /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-3.8.0/mcs/class/System.Web.Routing/System.Web.Routing/UrlRoutingModule.cs:88 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+<RunHooks>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x001ba] in /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-3.8.0/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:1050 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () [0x006f3] in /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-3.8.0/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:1260 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () [0x00000] in /Volumes/build-root-ramdisk/mono-3.8.0/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:932`

Is this something that is supported by mono at the moment? I can't find a whole lot of great resources online for this specifically.

Answer (score 1):

does not work now, please wait MONO team update or use WebApi 1(version=4.0)